# How bad is forgetting all old URLs when redesigning a site?

Tags: seo, redirects, url, redesign

I got to redesign a website for a very popular furniture and appliances company in my country. Currently this site receives around 100k organic traffic per month and 75% for home page.

There are almost 1000 pages indexed on Google. And the site was created more than 10 years ago and its structure is terrible.

I plan to build the new site using WordPress. (There is no online shopping part.)

The problem is redirecting old URLs to new URLs can be done only manually because of this terrible structure. So it takes huge time.

**So what happens if I don't redirect old pages to new pages?** How will it affect the organic traffic? My client agrees that he did not care traffic lost up to 30%.

Comment: You will miss more than 60% of your traffic, probably most user come from search result, i think it's bad idea if you not redirect urls, take some time and redirect them to new url, or simulate them.

Comment: Even your home page traffic will decrease because it is propped up by the value of links coming through all the other pages.  It might be worth finding a strategy where you can leave the old content at their existing URLs until they can be redirected.